# Jmeter Pacing between thread group Iterations

Tags: timer, jmeter

In Jmeter (5.4.1), I have the below thread group with 1 thread. I am controlling the frequency of the transaction using the constant timer. The constant timer_pacing in the image has the required pacing. I see that during execution, the constant timer is applied for each sample request in the particular thread group.

I am expecting all the samples before the contant timer_pacing to be executed one after the other immediately.What am I doing wrong here. Please advice.

[image]

alternatively similiar setup seems to works as expected for another thread group.

[image]

Comment: I just realized that the contant timer is applied for each sample in the thread group. how do I setup pacing between each itertaion in Jmeter. thanks

Comment: You may consider updating the question accordingly. [The timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) are processed before each sampler in the scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a delay between each iteration of each thread add a [Flow Control Action Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) as the first sampler and set the delay in the controller

If you want to add a random delay consider using JMeter function [Random](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) `${__Random(1000,5000,)}`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. All JMeter timers obey [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) so if you have Timers at the same level as Samplers - **all the timers will be applied to all the Samplers**
2. As per [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) documentation:

   > Note that timers are processed **before each sampler** in the scope in which they are found

So if you want to add a delay between `defaultPhotoUrl` and `Submit` requests you need to add a Constant Timer **as a child of the "Submit" request**